# Selenium dynamic ID and class

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Trying to open and post to FB. Pretty sure i'm going about adding a dynamic ID or class worng. Currtley it opens/signs into facebook, then i get a black overlay over my FB home page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('http://facebook.com')

emailelement = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@id="email"]')
emailelement.send_keys('email')

passelement = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@id="pass"]')
passelement.send_keys('password')

elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'.//*[@id="loginbutton"]')
elem.click()
print("Page open")

time.sleep(3)
```

`statuselement= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//*[@id='_5qtp']")`  **This is where things start to going south**

```
time.sleep(3)

statuselement.send_keys("Post hi")
time.sleep(5)

buttons = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("button")
time.sleep(5)
for button in buttons:
    if button.text == "Post":
        button.click()
```

xpath id and element on Facebook for Create A New Post

```
<span class="_5qtp">Create Post</span>
```

Once create a new post is clicked and text fields opens
[image]

Comment: Are you getting any sort of exception? You may need to look into the `enable_automation` flag.

Comment: Check FaceBook policies to check, before running any scripts on FB

Comment: So how like this? add chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension('path_to_extension')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use:
1- use "starts-with" function.

```
div[starts-with(@id,'something')]
```

2- use "contains" function.

```
 div[contains(@id,'something')]
```

or

3- use full xpath, that id is not necessary: like

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/form[1]/input[1]
```